# Using a stored cell address or value in a formula

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to save a cell address and use it in the formula , but i end up with a #value error. 
Can anybody explain how to properly store a cell address or a value in a variable and then use either or both in a formula.

Trying both cell value and address here,
This is the code i have :

```
Dim CellA1 As String
Dim CellA2 As String
Dim CellV1 As Single
Dim CellV2 As Single

Range("D20").Select

ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R16C:R[-2]C)"
CellA1 = ActiveCell.Address
CellV1 = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R16C:R[-1]C)"
CellA2 = ActiveCell.Address
CellV2 = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Panel Quantity"
Selection.Font.Bold = True

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Cost Price"
Selection.Font.Bold = True

ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Overheads(%)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Product(" & CellV1 & ",RC[-3])"
```

**UPDATE :**

The product formula is to give me a percentage of the total Cost price (Cells D22 & C24).
But these cells are not fixed and shift down as i add more items to the list.

Using the cell value in the formula works fine in the above code , thanks to @AJD 
But i prefer using the cell address in the formula.
Are there different ways of storing and using address or values?

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4QDk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Cell Value works with this :

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Product(" & CellV1 & ",RC[-3]%)"
```

How do i use the same formula with the Cell address ?

Answer (score 0):

The use of Active and Select burns my eyes. I have tidied that bit of code up as well. However, the last line should answer your question.  Or you could just use `CellA1` which you saved earlier. The Excel help for `Product` indicates this is the right format, but I have not test it.

```
Dim CellA1 As String
Dim CellA2 As String
Dim CellV1 As Single
Dim CellV2 As Single
Dim Rng as Range

'Set Rng = Range("D20").Offset(2, 0).Range("A1") ' Which worksheet?
Set Rng = Range("D22")
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R16C:R[-2]C)"
CellA1 = ActiveCell.Address
CellV1 = ActiveCell.Value

'Set Rng = Rng.Offset(-1, -1)
Set Rng = Range("C21")
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R16C:R[-1]C)"
CellA2 = ActiveCell.Address
CellV2 = ActiveCell.Value

'Set Rng = ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0)
Set Rng = Range("C23")
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "Overheads(%)"

'Set Rng = Rng.Offset(0, 4)
Set Rng = Range("G23")

Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=Product(" & CellV2 & ",RC[-3]%)"

' you have not specified which Cell address you wish to use.
' the following is an example where it can self reference. 
'Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=Product(" & Rng.AddressR1C1 & ",RC[-3]%)" ' don't mix relative and absolute.
```

**Update**: Based on comments.

A reasonable (but not the only) approach here is to set up a User Defined Function, with the key cells being entered as part of the formula line.

Put `=MyUDF(D22, C21, C23, G23)` in cell F24 (obviously, put the right cells into the formulas.

```
Function MyUDF(c1 as Range, c2 as Range, c3 as Range) as Variant
    c1.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R16C:R[-2]C)"
    c2.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R16C:R[-1]C)"
    c3.FormulaR1C1 = "Overheads(%)"
    MyUDF = c2.value * c1.value 
End Function
```

With this approach, you are not struggling to bounce around cells. The code above is based on your original code, and does not take into account the context in which you set this up (i.e. there are other things happening in your worksheet that may make this simpler).

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. My question is the total cost price and total quantity values do not always appear in cells D22 and C21. They move down as i add new items to the list. All i need to know is how do i account for this change in cell address and use that address in the 'product' formula

Comment: Basically the product formula at F24 should output D22*C24% with D22, C24 and C21 not fixed

Comment: @Denzil, I have left some commented code in there. But this will not achieve what you have asked in the comments. Your best approach is to edit your question - adding your comment above ("Basically the product formula at F24 should output D22*C24% with D22, C24 and C21 not fixed") because then you will get some specific (and different) examples of how to get and store the addresses.